# How much fetch responses does KafkaConsumer buffer?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Assume, I read topic from very beginning, so a lot of records are available on brokers.
I would like to understand how does consumer fetch logic works.

Does `KafkaConsumer` holds under the hood only 1 response per partition and waits it will be `poll()`-ed? If no, how match responses are buffered and what's the limitation? If yes, does it mean that no fetch requests would be even sent until last fetched record from partition would be polled?